# What is the best way to enlarge these thumbnails on click? Images currently not links

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my web portfolio as user-friendly as possible. This is my first-tier design. I am trying to figure out what the best way to go about enlarging these thumbnails would be. I would like to still be able to sort the images the way i currently have them set up. Any suggestions? currently they're just images, not links.

here is the link to my portfolio page: http://www.margierodrigues.com/Portfolio/portfolio.html

also any help centering these thumbnails would be appreciated. I'd like them always centered even when its sorted down to only 1-2 images.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#campaign').click(function() {
    showHide('campaign');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });
  $('#print').click(function() {
    showHide('print');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });
  $('#webinteractive').click(function() {
    showHide('webinteractive');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });
  $('#imaging').click(function() {
    showHide('imaging');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });
  $('#photography').click(function() {
    showHide('photography');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });
  $('#motionvideo').click(function() {
    showHide('motionvideo');
    toggleSelected(this);
  });

  $('#all').click(function() {
    showAll();
    toggleSelected(this);
  });

  showHide = function(target) {
    $('#contacts li').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass(target)) {
        $(this).show('slow');
      } else {
        $(this).hide('slow');
      }
    });
  }

  showAll = function() {
    $('#contacts li').each(function() {
      $(this).show('slow');
    });
  }

  toggleSelected= function(me) {
    $('div#filters ul li a').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass();
    });
    $(me).addClass('selected');
  }
});
```

```css
#logo {
  font-family: 'scriptina';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#nav {
  font-family: 'champagne';
  width: 80%;
  height: 150px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccf9de;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
}

#nav a {
  color: #484848;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
}

#name {
  font-family: 'biloxi';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 80px;
  color: #dfdfdf;
}

#description {
  font-family: 'champagne';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #dfdfdf;
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -120px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 640px;
  height: 480px;
  background: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -mox-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#content img {
  float: left;
  padding: 9px;
}

#content p {
  font-family: 'century gothic';
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 25px;
}

#resume img {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

p#caption {
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

#portfoliocategories li {
  font-family: 'champagne';
}

#footer {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'champagne';
  font-size: 10px;
  height: 3em;
  margin: 90px 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -100;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'scriptina';
  src: url('../fonts/Scriptina Pro.otf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'champagne';
  src: url('../fonts/Champagne & Limousines.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'biloxi';
  src: url('../fonts/Biloxi Script.ttf');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'century gothic';
  font-size: 12px;
}

#buttons img {
  display: block;
  padding: 9px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 6px;
  margin-top: 127px;
}

#thumbs {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 70px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

#thumbs li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 7px;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  list-style: none;
}

img#lr {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

img#back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: -60px;
  z-index: 50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

img#next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 630px;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
}

div#msg {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 275px 25px 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 565px;
  height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  border: solid 1px #fff;
}

#close {
  display: block;
  width: 14px;
  margin-left: 439px;
  margin-top: -15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbs {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 365px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#thumbs li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
}

#thumbs li img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#thumbs img {
  padding: 0px;
}

#filters {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: "century gothic";
}

a:link {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  color: #666;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#resources {
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

#resources li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

#filters li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 11px 0 0;
}

.selected {
  border: none 0px #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
  -mox-border-radius: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/logo.gif" alt="logo">
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <a href="portfolio.html">PORTFOLIO</a> |

  <a href="about.html">RESUME</a> |

  <a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
</div>


<div id="portfoliocategories">
  <header>
    <div id="filters">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="all">All</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="campaign">Campaign</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="print">Print</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="webinteractive">Web/Interactive</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="imaging">Imaging</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="photography">Photography</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" id="motionvideo">Motion/Video</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="thumbs">
    <ul>
      <li class="campaign 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/campaign_1.jpg" alt="campaign">
      </li>
      <li class="campaign 2"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/campaign_2.jpg" alt="campaign">
      </li>
      <li class="campaign 3"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/campaign_3.jpg" alt="campaign">
      </li>

      <li class="imaging 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_1.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 2"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_2.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 3"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_3.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 4"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_4.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 5"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_5.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 6"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_6.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 7"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_7.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>
      <li class="imaging 8"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/imaging_8.jpg" alt="imaging">
      </li>


      <li class="photography 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/photo_1.jpg" alt="photo">
      </li>
      <li class="photography 2"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/photo_2.jpg" alt="photo">
      </li>

      <li class="print 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_1.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>
      <li class="print 2"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_2.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>
      <li class="print 3"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_3.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>
      <li class="print 4"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_4.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>
      <li class="print 5"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_5.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>
      <li class="print 6"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/print_6.jpg" alt="print">
      </li>

      <li class="webinteractive 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/web_1.jpg" alt="web">
      </li>
      <li class="webinteractive 2"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/web_2.jpg" alt="web">
      </li>
      <li class="webinteractive 3"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/web_3.jpg" alt="web">
      </li>

      <li class="motionvideo 1"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/motion_1.jpg" alt="web">
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>




</div>

<div id="footer">
  &copy; MargieRodrigues, 2014
</div>
```

Comment: you mean to enlarge image on its `onclick` event?

Comment: ideally i'd like to enlarge the image onclick and have it open in the same window with the option to close it out and still be on the same page. does that make sense?

Comment: helpful link : http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/click-to-zoom-for-photos-adding-lightbox-effect-to-your-images/

Comment: to centralise your image, you can add text-align:centre" to the parent. example: <li class="campaign 2" style="text-align:center"> <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/campaign_2.jpg" alt="campaign"></li>

Comment: There are lots and lots of plugins available for this that will save a  lot of time

Answer (score 0):

To Trigger click events in `css`, you should do the following: encapsulate your image in `<a>`

```
<li class="campaign 1">  
    <a href="#ImgToDisplay">
        <img src="assets/images/thumbnails/campaign_1.jpg" alt="campaign"></a>
</li>
```

Set ImgToDisplay on hide by default and add the following in your css:

```
ImgToDisplay:target
{
  //set your image to visible here.
}
```

Moreover to enlarge ImgToDisplay on hover, just:

```
ImgToDisplay:active
{
   //enlarge your image here like below
    position: relative; z-index: 999; 
    -o-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -moz-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.03,1.03); 
    transform: scale(1.03,1.03);
}
```

Comment: i tried this but when i click on the image, it directs me to "safari can't find the file"

Comment: check `href` property... is it `#ImgToDisplay` or only `#`?

Comment: ok just checked it and i accidentally omitted the #, its corrected now and the cursor changes when i hover over my thumbnail but i am still stuck as to how i can get it to enlarge. I have larger versions of the thumbnails saved in my assets folder, how can i link to those?

Answer (score 0):

So I am a novice so please excuse me if this doesn't end up being helpful.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/scale-on-hover-with-webkit-transition/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

I looked into this and above are my references. Feel free to play with this and I hope it helps, it worked on my tests.

```
#thumbs li img:hover {
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
   transform: scale(1.1);
}
```